# Best practice: Drawing shape over Background

Tags: css, performance, flutter

I'm making a design in flutter and would like to have a wave shape over my background at the bottom (like in the image attached).

What is best practice to do it (even for example in html - css).

Is it better to overlay a image shape to the bottom of the background e.g. a white wave-shape or to achieve the effect by drawing the wave-shape programmaticaly - ( In flutter for example by using the path widget.
Or in css by drawing it)?

Img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdcFI.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [ClipPath](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ClipPath-class.html) .

To achieve that easily, you can use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_custom_clippers) package.

Further, you can make your own clipper.

Comment: Thanks. But the question is: is it best practice to use a ClipPath and 'draw' everything or to use an image that has the shape of ClipPath and put it as background together with the  background-color?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think that best practice is the easiest way to do anything. With ClipPath you will have more control about what drawing and all benefits that a Container has (decoration, shape, sizes, etc) and you do not need to load an asset to your app.

Comment: Can I change the wave amount curve? I didn't see anything that helps.